# How can I deactivate an jailbroken iOS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Sometimes the `activation` option from the PwnageTool does bring your GSM in an unusable state if you have and iPhone that is locked to other network than AT&T.

All I remember is that it was a tool that I installed using Cydia that was able to deactivate the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should disable activation (it's hacktivation) when jailbreaking if your phone is unlocked (or locked to your carrier).

In **PwnageTool** you should choose `Expert` and deselect the `Activate the phone` checkbox.